# c# pass parameters from a previous action

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm writing an application that will have a datagridview control and 4 textboxes.

One requirement for the application is that when the user double clicks a row in the datagrid, the 4 textboxes fill with the corresponding textboxes with the data -> this is already done and working. Once the user has edited the field and clicks OK, they will be saved on the datagridview.

On the other hand, if the user clicks a button called "Add Register", the same buttons will be enabled and once they click OK a new register with the data in the textboxes will be created.

The thing is that I don't know how and I have not found any information about knowing if I should edit a row (and which one) or add a new one when OK is clicked.

In other words: how can I know if I'm coming from an "edit" request or an "Add register" request when the user presses "OK"?

Thanks!

Comment: What is "OK"? Is it a button? What GUI framework are you using? WinForms? WPF? Something else? If WinForms, objects have a `.Tag` property that you could use. Alternatively, you could store the current edit type in the class object when you start adding/editing.

Comment: A datagridview has a property called edit.  When true a blank row is added to the DGV so new data can be edited.  So if the selected row is the last row of the DGV you add the row.  Otherwise, you modify the selected row.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow.
The simplest way to achieve this is to have a boolean field on your form, e.g. bool isEdit.  When the user double clicks a line in the DataGridView (a handler for which you say you have working), then set the field to true.  Within the Add register button handler, set the field to false.
Now within your OK handler, you simply examine the value of the isEdit field to know, if you are adding or editing!

I have done a lot (a very great lot!) of such DataGridView forms.  Personally I do not like to combine the form with data entry.  I prefer to leave my DataGridView form as totally read-only, and then when the user clicks edit or add buttons, I display a separate modal form to handle the data entry.  On saving from the modal form, I refresh the grid.

HTH